# What does this musn't mean?

Tags: modal-verbs

> [13ia]He mustn’t have done it deliberately.
>   [13ib]He can’t have done it deliberately
>   . . . 
>   [14] i  A: What has happened to Ed?    B: He must have overslept. [subjective]
>            ii  If I'm older than Ed and Ed is older than Jo,  I must be older than Jo. [objective]
>   . . . 
>   Because of the pragmatic weakening found with subjective *must*, [13ia] is not pragmatically equivalent to [ib], which is stronger, more categorical. *Can’t* would be preferred when the matter is regarded as obvious and particularly in denying something that has been asserted (*He says it was Jill but it can’t have been*), **with *mustn’t* used - by those for whom it is not restricted to deontic modality - when it’s a question of arriving at a negative conclusion (*He mustn’t have told her after all*)**.(CGEL, p181)

The bolded part is hard to understand.

(1) To where is ***with mustn’t used*** connected syntactically?
(2) Is it saying the example ***He musn’t have told her after all*** has not deontic but epistemic modality?

Would you explain the overall meaning of the bolded part?

(* I mis-wrote epidemic below for epistemic: I'm much obliged to snailboat for correcting the word above.)

[image]

Comment: (1) Temporarily ignore the "parenthetical" *- by those for whom it is not restricted to deontic modality -*, then interpret *with **mustn’t** used* as a slightly stylised turn of phrase which could be directly replaced by *and **mustn't** is used*. (2) Yes, it's saying that some speakers don't restrict their use of ***mustn't*** to contexts involving what people may/ought to do. Those people are happy to say, for example *"X **mustn't** be true"* in contexts where they've concluded it's simply *not possible* for X to be true (regardless of whether X being true is "permissible" or not).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thank you Mr. Fumblefingers. A replier in [Korean website](http://k.daum.net/qna/view.html?qid=5DIdP) told me to ask this question and got wonderful answer, and feedback it to her. I guess you and StoneyB might be a bit famous in the site, for I now and then quote your sayings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is "mustn't" used this way in BrE? In AmE my impression is that it's never contracted in this sense; you have to say *must not* and *mustn't* is reserved for deontics.

Comment: @StoneyB, Thank you very much. For your comment I've been improved the understanding, AND the bottom of 181 page is flowering full of both of your explanations.

Comment: @StoneyB: It's an odd one, this. I think this use of ***must*** always sounds a bit dated/formal. And although contracted forms are usually more informal, in this particular case it seems to me even more *formal* when the negation is contracted. A fairly "bulletproof" text string to avoid false positives is ["mustn't have understood"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mustn't+have+understood%22&oq=%22mustn't+have+understood%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1190j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), which people obviously *do* use at least sometimes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think epistemic *must* is fairly common over here: "I thought Ryan was gonna be here. He musta had to stay late." "I thought Ryan was gonna be here. He musnotta gotten my email." *Musnotta* has the same prosody as *field hockey* or *bartender*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Temporarily ignore the parenthetical “by those for whom it is not restricted to deontic modality”, then interpret “with **mustn’t** used” as a slightly stylised turn of phrase which could be directly replaced by “and **mustn’t** is used.”
2. Yes, it’s saying that some speakers don’t restrict their use of mustn't to contexts involving what people may/ought to do. Those people are happy to say, for example, “X mustn’t be true” in contexts where they’ve concluded that it’s simply not possible for X to be true (regardless of whether X being true is “permissible” or not).

Comment: Originally posted as a comment [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11726/what-does-this-musnt-mean/11905#comment-19936) by [FumbleFingers](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers).